# Having an issue with inheritance. Need to call subclass method from a manager class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am currently writing a program that will run a race between four different "racers." Each of these racers moves in a unique way, and as a result must have their own class. These four unique "racerType" classes must be subclasses of a generic "Racer" superclass. All of the actual race running must be done from "Manager" class. The race runs to 100 units, and the first racer to reach this distance wins.

The requirements are as follows:

A generic racer class that serves as a superclass for the individual racer classes. It does not need to
be abstract, but is not intended to be instantiated into an object.

A specific racer class for each of the racer types described above. These classes are all subclass of the generic racer class.

A manager class that creates at least one racer of each type described above, simulate a race, and notify the user of the winner. Note: GUI is not required, and not desired.

I'm having some issues making this work correctly and am not sure if I am designing it in an efficient manner.

I have a Manager class, a Racer superclass, and four RacerType_ subclasses. Each of the RacerType_ subclasses has their own movement patterns. What I can't figure out is how to call the unique movement methods from the Manager class, or even from the Racer superclass. What would be the best way to call the four different movement methods, and then keep track of their values to add to the total distance of each racer's position?

Comment: what are your attempts on this question please show us what you have done https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Racer superclass abstract and include an abstract method called move. Then when you extend Racer to each of the racer types, you can write unique methods that all return a value indicating the distance to move.

This enables you to create a list of racers and call the move method directly from the array

like this

```
Racer racerLists[] = new Racer[4];
racerLists[0] = new Motorcycle();
racerLists[1] = new Car();
racerLists[2] = new Bike();
racerLists[4] = new Runner();

for(int i=0; i<racerLists.length; i++)
{
    racerLists[i].move();
}
```

each racer will have their unique move method called.

Don't forget to mark this as an answer if this answers your question.
Thanks

Comment: please follow java naming convention http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: If you are talking about the iterator i, I haven't figured out how to make it lowercase. The software keeps autocorrecting it from an i to an I.

Comment: `racerLists[4]` seems wrong. Did you mean `racerLists[3]`?